# Fuzzy Grouping from OLE DB Source Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, package

I have created SSIS Package for Fuzzy Grouping.

Source: `OLE DB`

Destination: `OLE DB`

Transformation: `Fuzzy Grouping`

I need to run the package using config file and made following settings for that.

Settings:

1. Package Level:

   1.1 `DelayValidation: True`

   1.2 `Protection Level: DontSaveSensitive` and Also tried with `EncrypSensitiveWithUserKey`
2. Data Flow Task Level:

   2.1 `DelayValidation: True`
3. Solution Level:

   3.1  `Run64BitRuntime: False`
4. Drop and recreated Connection Manager.
5. Created Config file right click from control flow -> Package Configration -> Enable Configration -> Add -> Selected Only Connection String + Initial Catalog + Password + UserName + ServerName.

Still unable to get the job done.

Getting following error message:

[image]